# OpenSIS installation error

Tags: php

In step 2 of the OpenSIS installation I face with this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(0) , start_date date, end_date date, published_profiles characte' at line 9`

What can I do?

Comment: PlZ give us full code

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,494735,494845#msg-494845

> Removing the "(0)" from "Timestamp (0)" fixed the problem.
>
> Thank you.

Look for:

```
CREATE TABLE PORTAL_NOTES( 

id NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
school_id NUMERIC, 
syear NUMERIC( 4, 0 ) , 
title CHARACTER VARYING( 255 ) , 
content CHARACTER VARYING( 5000 ) , 
sort_order NUMERIC, 
published_user NUMERIC, 
published_dateTIMESTAMP( 0 ) , 
start_date DATE, 
end_date DATE, 
published_profiles CHARACTER VARYING( 255 ) 
);
```